# How to plot 4D array with 2 sliders using PyPlot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 4D data set (for those who care, its an astronomical Position-Position-Temperature-Opacity image) in a numpy array, that I need to plot in an interactive way. While there are programs to do this, none of them can handle the unusual form that my data steps in (but I can worry about that, thats not part of the question).

I know how to get it plotting with one `Slider`, but really I need to plot the image with 2 `Sliders`, one for each of temperature and opacity.

My MWE of a 3D array code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(300,300,10)

axis = 2
s = [slice(0, 1) if i == axis else slice(None) for i in xrange(array.ndim)]
im = array[s].squeeze()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
l = ax.imshow(im, origin = 'lower')
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.95, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

slider = Slider(ax, 'Temperature', 0, array.shape[axis] - 1,
                    valinit=0, valfmt='%i')

def update(val):
    ind = int(slider.val)
    s = [slice(ind, ind + 1) if i == axis else slice(None)
             for i in xrange(array.ndim)]
    im = array[s].squeeze()
    l.set_data(im)
    fig.canvas.draw()

slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Any way to do it with 2 sliders?

EDIT: The problem I am having is I dont know how to expand to 2 sliders. Particularly how to adapt the line

```
s = [slice(0, 1) if i == axis else slice(None) for i in xrange(array.ndim)]
```

and how to modify the `update` function when I go from `np.random.rand(300,300,10)` to `np.random.rand(300,300,10,10)`. I supposed I will need to declare both a `T_axis = 2` and `B_axis = 3` rather than simply an `axis = 2`, but beyond that, I am rather stuck as to how to modify it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want to have 2 sliders, use two sliders. If you then encounter a problem, we need a real [mcve], not some "almost" one.

Comment: I have updated to a fully working bit of code, and outlined my problem better. 

Maybe I am reading too much into it and simply not seeing how to modify the `s = ` line. It looks like a list, I assume its a list. So I could do it with a more expanded for loop and if,elif,else statement tree, but im not sure if thats even what its doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I interprete the data structure, you have an array of shape `(300,300,n,m)`, where `n` is the number of temperatures and `m` is the number of opacities. The image to show for the `i`th temperature and the `j`th opacity is hence, `array[:,:,i,j]`.

You now need of course two different silders where one determines the value of `i` and the other of `j`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(300,300,10,9)
# assuming you have for each i=Temperature index and j =Opacity index
# an image array(:,:,i,j)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l = ax.imshow(array[:,:,0,0], origin = 'lower')

axT = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.95, 0.65, 0.03])
axO = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.90, 0.65, 0.03])

sliderT = Slider(axT, 'Temperature', 0, array.shape[2]-1, valinit=0, valfmt='%i')
sliderO = Slider(axO, 'Opacity', 0, array.shape[3]-1, valinit=0, valfmt='%i')

def update(val):
    i = int(sliderT.val)
    j = int(sliderO.val)
    im = array[:,:,i,j]
    l.set_data(im)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sliderT.on_changed(update)
sliderO.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect. I was just about to post that I found a way to do it, but yours is far more elegant and easy to understand.